# Python TKinter record GUI button press?

Tags: python, user-interface

I've been fiddling with this piece of code trying to figure out how to register button presses once you have placed them in a GUI and hit a wall.  I'm just trying to get it to output the corresponding number upon button press.

Here is what I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *

def click(self, key):
    self.entry.insert(END, key)

root = Tk()
labels = [['1','2','3'], ['4','5','6'], ['7','8','9'], ['*','0','#']]

for r in range(4):
    for c in range(3):

        def cmd(x = labels[r][c]):
            self.click(key)

        button = Button(root,
                        relief=RAISED,
                        padx=10,
                        text=labels[r][c],
                        command = cmd)
        button.grid(row=r+1, column=c)
```

Getting an error about no global "self" defined.  Possibly a simple error that has gone over my head, but I've tried about everything I can think of.

Comment: It looks as though you're copying and pasting code from a tutorial that used classes, and have no classes of your own in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run functions such as *click* that take *self* as a parameter. By using

```
self.click
```

you are referring to the object that should be created before calling these methods. You either need to remove the *self* or, in an ideal world, create the required classes and then use self.